# Google App Script - PayPal API - Get Access Token

Tags: google-apps-script, paypal-sandbox

I have this function that should give me the access token in cURL

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
    -u "client_id:secret" \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

source:https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

but when i try to run the function (that is supposed to be the same) in google app script the error is always: "invalid token". What am i doing wrong?

```
 function lol(){
   var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", {
     "Accept": "application/json",
     "Accept-Language": "en_US",
     "CLIENT_ID":"SECRET",
     "grant_type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   })
   Logger.log(request.getContentText());
 }
```

CLIENT_ID & SECRET are personal and copied from my PayPal account.

Comment: For one thing, you need to explicitly designate that you are making a POST request.  `var information = {"client_id":"SECRET"}; var options = {'method':'post','payload':information}; UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);`  See the [link to Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- At UrlFetchApp, as Sandy Good said, you are required to explicitly designate the method. In your case, it's "POST".
- At UrlFetchApp, the default `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- The option `-u` for curl command is the basic authorization.
- The option `-H` for curl command is the header.
- At the [curl sample](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token) of PayPal, `grant_type` is `client_credentials`.

The script which reflected above points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function myFunction(){
  var client_id = "client_id"; // Please input your client_id
  var secret = "secret"; // Please input your client secret

  var options = {
    method: "post",
    headers : {
      "Authorization" : " Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(client_id + ":" + secret),
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Accept-Language": "en_US"
    },
    payload: {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
  };
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", options);
  Logger.log(request.getContentText())
}
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It's working :)